getting an empty array in mongo db get request while using aggregate
so i am new to mongo db and don't know why my logic is not working...its showing me an empty array when i try to get a value of specficly something,
here is the code
let totalEarnedCurrentMonth;
    
        try {
            const { startDate, endDate } = req.query;
    
            // Calculate the start and end dates for the current month if not provided
            let currentMonthStartDate, currentMonthEndDate;
            if (!startDate && !endDate) {
                const currentDate = new Date();
                currentMonthStartDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1);
                currentMonthEndDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
            } else {
                currentMonthStartDate = new Date(startDate);
                currentMonthEndDate = new Date(endDate);
            }
    
            totalEarnedCurrentMonth = await Ledger.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        projectId: { $in: await Project.find({ userId: req.user._id }, '_id') },
                        date: { $gte: currentMonthStartDate, $lte: currentMonthEndDate }
                    }
                },
                { $group: { _id: null, totalAmount: { $sum: '$amount' } } }
            ]);
    
            // Extract the total earnings from the aggregation result
            // const totalEarned = totalEarnedCurrentMonth.length ? totalEarnedCurrentMonth[0].totalAmount : 0;
            console.log(totalEarnedCurrentMonth);
            // res.status(200).json({ totalEarned });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
        }

Now the data which shows that i do have data in my database with specific needs
{ "_id": "66301f9a8b8889c0eac6d251", "projectId": "66301f108b8889c0eac6d248", "amount": 350, "type": "normal", "date": "2024-04-29T22:30:50.145Z", "__v": 0 },
i ahve multiple entries like this but still the get request on the the above api call is sending me an value of 0 why?? What mistake am i doing
Note: i tried it yester which is the month of  april so i should be getting an resposne in get request right?
To get the value of current month ledger and rectify my mistake


Try running the query by hard coding the value instead of using the passed-in variable. If you are able to get it, that means the problem is due to passed-in variable. Otherwise, it is due to your query being incorrect/pointing to the wrong collection/DB. 2. How did you store the date fields, date/timestamp, string?


1.I used the hard coded data but still the response is 0
2.
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const ledgerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
amount: { type: Number, required: true },
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
type: { type: String, enum: ['normal', 'maintenance'], required: true }
});
const Ledger = mongoose.model('Ledger', ledgerSchema);
export default Ledger;
this is the code for the ledger model @YongShun

We would like to help you. We need to debug this step by step. step 1: From your actual database, please spot and keep a copy of the actual MongoDB documents with respect to  “Current Month earning” for a particular user and a month. step 2: Please execute the same aggregation query by hard coding the query parameters in a Mongo Shell instance. step 3: Check the two results. The two results - step 1 and step 2, must be the same. step 4: Please execute the same aggregation query by keeping the same hard coded query parameters. This time let this be executed by your mongoose code. ...

...step 5 Check the results: again step 3 and step 4 must yield the same results. If you have got this much matched, then the only code left out to check are the codes with respect to calculate the dates. We shall do this once you have gone through the steps from 1 to 5 successfully.
